# How to set Reminder notification on Android?

Tags: android

i want to display reminder on selected date and time on notification bar of android from my application .But that one should be populated even without the application.Whenever My android devices booted up and one the selected time with/without my application it should display notification in specified time like alarm.
please help me how to do this?.

I found some links about Alarm Manager,Notification manager. Give me the idea and some links otherwise sample snippet.

Comment: Wrote a tutorial. Notification Reminders: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to add an alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheServiceYouWantToStart.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time_To_wake, pending);
```

Comment: the mentioned code isn't work if i come out from my application.I want that alarm service shoul work without my appl also.

Comment: yes this will work ... It will start the `TheServiceYouWantToStart`
You have to add code to onStartCommand

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void notifyIcon(Context context){

NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.your_app_notification, "", System.currentTimeMillis());

/**
*Setting these flags will stop clearing your icon
*from the status bar if the user does clear all 
*notifications.
*/
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

//If you want to open any activity on the click of the icon.

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "title", null, contentIntent);
    notifier.notify(1, notification);

//To cancel the icon ...
    notifier.cancel(1);

}
```

Here is custom_notification_layout.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Don't forget to clear your app icon when appropriate If you set above flag.