# how to set up Holiday Reminder app

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android programming. I want to create an app which reminds shows a list of holidays to the user and the user selects which days he wants to get reminded about by clicking check boxes and then pressing a button. I have the UI set up but am stumped how to setup the alarm manager . Can someone show me how to go about doing this, i have tried many things but none seem to be working. Thanks in advance.

The code that I tried is :
                `

public void sn(int m,int d,int h,int mi,int s,int y,int id)
            {
        Long time1 = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+20000 ;

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mi);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, s);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
    long time2 = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long time =time2 ;
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"ticker",time);
    Intent i= new Intent(TR.this,TR.class);
    PendingIntent p= PendingIntent.getActivity(TR.this,0,i,0);
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(TR.this, "Title", "contentText", p);
    nm.notify(id,notify);
}
```

`

whenever I try this code it springs up notification immediately instead of waiting for the set time. Also it gives warning about Deprecation at 2 places- "new Notification(..)" and "notify.setLatestEventInfo(..)"

Comment: What all have you tried? Please paste the code and then you can be helped. Till then you can refer to this [link] (http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html)

Comment: This link should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283959/how-to-set-reminder-notification-on-android?rq=1

Comment: @HarshSingal:Thanks a lot. the link was very useful

Comment: Glad to help. I have posted the link as an answer. Please accept the same. :)

Comment: @HarshSinghal can you please tell me how i can use notification manager instead of alarm manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the link as answer as it has helped you solve your query.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283959/how-to-set-reminder-notification-on-android?rq=1)